# Rearrangement of symbols

Tags: symbols

I want to make the size of the symbols  (+,-,=,<,>,neq) as in the below image.
[image]

I just want it to be like this in size. I don't want their thickness to change.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,A5paper]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$x+y-z=c<d>c\neq b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are best really to choose another font. A font is a unified work by the font designer if you distort individual symbols then that unity is broken, you can't easly scale those symbols up without making them thicker and if you find another font with larger + rather than scaling, then perhaps that font will be suitable for all symbols.

Comment: Is there a site where I can find such a font? I looked at some sites but I could find very few packages.

Comment: (a) Use `@` to ping a user, otherwise they will not know. (b) What font was used in the image? That might help to start looking. (c) If something is made bigger, it *must* change thickness (and height and width), mustn't it? Otherwise, you are in effect re-designing the font.

Comment: I used tgheros and mathastext in image. @Cicada

Comment: If I understand correctly, for tgheros, you want to change the size (width & height) but keep the thickness constant? Since *w* x *h* = *t*, how can both requirements be achieved? In any case, having a different *t* implies a different font by design. So the question now resolves into: either: (a) what do you want to achieve in the first place that is unsatisfactory now; and/or (b) what values of *w*, *h*, *t* do you want? (e.g. `+` must be 0.92 of `x`-height etc), and then find a font that meets that design.

Comment: Thank you for your support if i can't i will try to find a different font

Comment: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it might help you choose, here are some OpenType fonts that are part of the TexLive distribution and have "math' in the name:

[image: some maths fonts]

Latin Modern Math, Tex Gyre Bonum Math, and XITS Math look like having a relatively big `+`, so could be possibilities.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmathfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\testeq[1]{\colorbox{blue!5}{\makebox[0.45\linewidth][r]{#1}}: \setmathfont{#1}$x+y-z=c<d>c\neq b$\par}

\newcommand\ffonta{GFS Artemisia}
\newcommand\ffontb{Asana Math}
\newcommand\ffontc{Erewhon Math}
\newcommand\ffontd{FiraMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffonte{Garamond-Math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontf{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}
\newcommand\ffontg{KpMath-Bold.otf}
\newcommand\ffonth{KpMath-Light.otf}
\newcommand\ffonti{KpMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffontj{KpMath-Sans.otf}
\newcommand\ffontk{KpMath-Semibold.otf}
\newcommand\ffontl{LibertinusMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffontm{latinmodern-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontn{NewCMMath-Book.otf}
\newcommand\ffonto{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffontp{STEPMath-Bold.otf}
\newcommand\ffontq{STEPMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffontr{STIXMath-Regular.otf}
\newcommand\ffonts{STIX2Math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontt{texgyrebonum-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontu{texgyredejavu-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontv{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontw{texgyreschola-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffontx{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\newcommand\ffonty{XITSMath-Bold.otf}
\newcommand\ffontz{XITSMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
        {\testeq{\csname ffont\x\endcsname}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very compliments for the elegance of the answer.